# The Security to the Party [Part 13]

Tags: word-problem, password

After pretty sick 12 parties, obviously 13th party occured during "Halloween".

Halloween themed party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing ~ his famous recipe for Evil Spaghetti!

The only guests that may attend are people the host knows and trusts, whom he gave the password to enter to.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "1", and the guest replies "3" and guard let him pass.

The second guest arrives. The security says "3", the guest replies "3" and guard let him pass.

The third guest arrives. The security says "9", the guest replies "3" and guard let him pass.

You're friend thinks he got it all figured out. He approaches the security and guard say "7", when he replies "3", guard looked to your friend waited for a bit before talking. Your friend was tense and holding his position to dodge possible elephant attacks. Suddenly guard said "Welcome Sir" and let him in. Unfortunately your friend still needs you to steal evil spaghetti recipe.

Then, another guest arrives, you seem to get the same pattern, security says "2" and he says "2" to get in.

You walk up to security and get "13", what is the correct response?

**Hint 1:**

> Meanwhile one more guest arrives, guard says "4" and guest replies with "1".

**Hint 2:**

> Later one more guest arrives, guard says "14" and guest replies with "4".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ans is **4**. Common letters between digit in words and word "Halloween". 13 = Thirteen, so here 'h','e','e' & 'n' four letters common between 13 & Halloween.

Comment: that's brilliant

Answer (score 4):

> `3`. Because, even number was 2 and odds are 3.

Comment: I was typing this response when you got it in

Comment: @skv let's see if we are correct. I didn't really see any other pattern.

Comment: well, this is not the correct answer/reasoning but here you go another guest arrives while you are waiting :)

Comment: This question is driving me crazy :) can't for the life of me figure it out... I've even tried logarithms!